# What does "sweet bird" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrases

I've come across the phrase "sweet bird". It's been translated into my native language as a "sweet-voiced bird". I wonder if the translation is right? Is a "sweet bird" a common phrase to describe a bird with a pleasant voice?

Comment: Please provide an example of the context in which this occurs.

Comment: Bird is slang for girl in English.

Comment: I reckon it's not even a weak collocation. As an accidental string, it is off-topic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - apparently it used to be: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sweet+bird&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csweet%20bird%3B%2Cc

Comment: On account of their name, ***The The*** have always been a difficult band to search for on the internet. But I always liked their [***Sweet Bird of Truth***](https://songmeanings.com/songs/view/3530822107858700554/) - *This is your captain calling--"with an urgent warning"
We're above the Gulf of Arabia--"our altitude is falling"
& I can't hold her up--"there's no time for thinking"
All hands on deck--"**this bird is sinking**"*

Comment: (Modelled after Tennessee Williams' [*Sweet Bird of **Youth***](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Sweet_Bird_of_Youth/uc2RIum5vL8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22sweet+bird+of+youth%22&printsec=frontcover), I suppose.

Comment: Without context it could mean anything from pleasant-tasting poultry to an attractive woman or nice airplane.

Comment: We need more context. As others have pointed out, this could mean at least three different things. I'm assuming you really want an answer, though.